# Можно ли изменить название префикса (ресурса) в URL'е?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть ресурс и множество маршрутов в нем

```
resources :hallo, only: [:index] do
    member do
      get :get_wizard
      .....
      .....
      .....
      .....
    end
  end
```

Сейчас Url выглядит так - `/hallo/1/get_wizard`
Можно ли изменить название маршрута, чтобы путь выглядел так - `/original/1/get_wizard`?
Сделать одиночные маршруты, и не использовать ресурсы не могу - маршрутов слишком много.

Comment: Для всего блока `resources`?

Comment: да, чтобы вместо `hallo` для всех маршрутов было `original`

Comment: Тогда посмотрите [документацию к `resources`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources).